# Bootstrap group button javascript event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I set a value into hidden field when I call this button toggle?

```
$(".btn").first().button("toggle");
```

Comment: what's wrong? down voted? No reason specified and I don't know who down voted. I think they deserve a down vote!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind is, when i call `button("toggle")` it add a class `active` to its container. so we check if the container has class `active`, do something.

Try

```
var button_first = $(".btn").first();

button_first.on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).button("toggle");
   if( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
     //Do something
     // $('hidden_field').val()
   }
}):
```

Edit:

On page load

```
$(function() {
    var button_first = $(".btn").first();
    button_first.button('toggle');
    if( button_first.hasClass('active') ) {
     //Do something
     // $('hidden_field').val()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I want this to happen onpage loads first time.